# Is it possible to do a Trigger in Access that will insert a new row in a table in SqlServer Database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an Access 2003 Database and want to add a trigger upon new row in Files Table to insert a new row with new info to another table in SqlServer 2008 database?

Is this possible after all?  Or are there any other better methods/tools to accomplish this? I would appreciate some code snippets to get started.

Thanks for your sincere help!

Comment: Are you saying you have one table in Access and one table in SQL Server? If not, why do you want to create a trigger in Access, which you cannot do in 2003. You need to supply more information.

Comment: HI,Thanks for answering. The access table has 12 fields. I am interested in only 3- FileName,Subject and Origin.  The SqlServer table files has got many more files that are not found in the access table.. i.e. Access files are a subset of all files. Ideally I would have 1 full table in sql server and the 3 fields required in the access table point to this table to get values. Then when creating a new file in Accees Form, this will create a new row in Sqlserver with FileName,Subject and Origin and another row in Access including row ID returned from sql server together with the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have created a windows service that will check for new rows in the Access Files table, by holding an index on the last rowID primary key. New rows are read and its data is sent to the Sql Server database.

Triggers would have been a better approach, but db is on Access 2003. The service runs twice a day and so far seems working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access doesn't support triggers. But if you insert/update data on the form, you are able to use events and VBA. This article should help you: [Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: MS Access 2010 has data macros, which can function in a similar way to triggers.

Comment: Yes, Access 2010 does have data triggers. These are real triggers and this is true engine level code that runs at update time. In fact, the code runs even if you don't have Access installed and update the table with com automation, or even ODBC from vb.net or even FoxPro.